# Installing Cordova

Tags: cordova

I am getting this error message when trying to install Cordova:

```
C:\>npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\invitado\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.6
npm ERR! path C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-208fc6c5
npm ERR! code ENOENT                                                            npm ERR! errno -4058                                                            npm ERR! syscall rename
                                                                                npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-208fc6c5' -> 'C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-208fc6c5' -> 'C:\Users\invitado\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log                                                   npm ERR! code 1

C:\>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert with Cordova but have you tried cleaning out the cache?
If not, you can do so via the following:

```
npm cache clean
```

If that doesn't work it might be worthwhile visiting the following resource:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826